# SQL Data won't show up in JTable

Tags: java, sql, swing, jtable

I have a program that when the user clicks on a button that the SQL data from the database shows in the JTable. Problem is when i click the button nothing shows up. But when i print the variables, it does show the correct value. So why won't anything show up in my JTable?

Note: JTable/Button was added with GUI design.

Code:

```
import connection.connection;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

/**
 *
 * @author peter
 */
public class Tabel extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form Tabel
     */
    public Tabel() {
        initComponents();
    }                      

    private void showBtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        String[] columns = {"Nummer", "Adres", "Postcode", "Plaats",
                            "capaciteit"};

        String sql = "SELECT * FROM uitgiftepunt";

        try (
                Connection conn = connection.getConnection();
                Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
                ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
            ){
               DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(columns, 0);
                while (rs.next()) {
                    int nummer = rs.getObject("nummer", Integer.class);
                    String adres = rs.getObject("adres", String.class);
                    String postcode = rs.getObject("postcode", String.class);
                    String plaats = rs.getObject("plaats", String.class);
                    int cap = rs.getObject("capaciteit", Integer.class);
                    model.addRow(new Object[]{nummer,adres,postcode,plaats,cap});   
                    System.out.printf("%d, %s, %s, %s, %d", nummer,adres,postcode,plaats,cap);

                }

                jTable1.setModel(model);
                jScrollPane1 = new JScrollPane(jTable1);
                jTable1.setFillsViewportHeight(true);


            } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Tabel.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }                                       

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {



        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Tabel().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JTable jTable1;
    private javax.swing.JButton showBtn;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: Post a [mcve]...

Comment: updated the code

Comment: still not an MCVE. where is `jTable1/jScrollPane1` added to the frame for instance?

Comment: This is not a frame but a form. I just dragged the jTable in the form.

Comment: @Peterrosevelt 1) it is a frame since your class extends JFrame, 2) we don't care how the frame was created or what IDE you used. All the matters is the code that you compile or execute. The code you posted doesn't show where the table/scrollpane is added to the frame, so we can only guess that you never add the scrollpane to the frame and that is why the table is not visible.

Comment: *"This is not a frame but a form."* Stop talking like your IDE and speak Java. The statement `Tabel extends javax.swing.JFrame` indicates it is, indeed, a Swing based `JFrame`.

Comment: (1-) You already have a working example from your last question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44287646/jtable-only-displays-last-record-from-table. So look at your working code and see how this code is different. In other words do some basic debugging.

Comment: You neet to learn how to format your code for easy readability, some ide(s) have shortcuts for that, e,g, NetBeans (ctr+L_shift+F) in inteliji IDEA use (ctr+alt+L)

Answer (score 0):

**This is a guaranteed solution unless you have SQL exception which would have show up in your logs**
Reuse this code snippet specifically the createView() and buildtabalemodel functions.

```
public class JTableSQLProblem extends JFrame{
JScrollPane scrollPane;

public JTableSQLProblem(){
    setSize(1000,500);
    setLayout( new FlowLayout());

    scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
    scrollPane.getViewport().add(createView());

    add(scrollPane);
    repaint();
    setVisible(true);
}
  public static DefaultTableModel buildtableModel(ResultSet resultSet) throws SQLException {

    ResultSetMetaData metaData = resultSet.getMetaData();

    Vector<String> columnNames = new Vector<>();
    int columnCount = metaData.getColumnCount();
    for (int column = 1; column <= columnCount; column++) {
        columnNames.add(metaData.getColumnName(column));

    }

    Vector<Vector<Object>> data = new Vector<>();
    while (resultSet.next()) {
        Vector<Object> vector = new Vector<Object>();
        for (int columnIndex = 1; columnIndex <= columnCount; columnIndex++) {
            vector.add(resultSet.getObject(columnIndex));
        }
        data.add(vector);
    }

    return new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);

}
 private static JTable createView() {
    try {
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/youtdatabasename","root","");
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(
                "SELECT * FROM yourtablename");

        JTable table = new JTable(buildtableModel(rs));
        UIDefaults defaults = UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults();
        defaults.put("Table.alternateRowColor", Color.decode("#f5f5f5"));
        table.setSelectionBackground(Color.decode("#1e90ff"));
        table.setSelectionForeground(Color.WHITE);
        table.setRowHeight(30);
        table.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        table.setShowGrid(false);
        table.setFont(new Font("calibri", Font.PLAIN, 16));

        JTableHeader tableHeader = table.getTableHeader();
        tableHeader.setBackground(Color.decode("#B0E0E6"));
        tableHeader.setForeground(Color.black);
        tableHeader.setFont(new Font("Calibri Bold", Font.BOLD, 14));
        tableHeader.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.WHITE));

        rs.close();
        return table;
    } catch (SQLException | HeadlessException exc) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, exc);
        return new JTable();
    }
}
public static void main(String[]args){
    new JTableSQLProblem();
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to create a separate method to create the table

```
public static DefaultTableModel buildTableModel(ResultSet rs)throws SQLException {

    ResultSetMetaData metaData = rs.getMetaData();

    // names of columns
    Vector<String> columnNames = new Vector<String>();
    int columnCount = metaData.getColumnCount();
    for (int column = 1; column <= columnCount; column++) {
        columnNames.add(metaData.getColumnName(column));
    }

    // data of the table
    Vector<Vector<Object>> data = new Vector<Vector<Object>>();
    while (rs.next()) {
        Vector<Object> vector = new Vector<Object>();
        for (int columnIndex = 1; columnIndex <= columnCount; columnIndex++) {
            vector.add(rs.getObject(columnIndex));
        }
        data.add(vector);
    }

    return new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);
}
```

In this way you create a new DefaultTableModel passing the data and columnNames as parameters, the first is a Vector of Vector and the second a Vector

And then

```
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
JTable table = new JTable(buildTableModel(rs));
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
```

In previous table I used I had the problem that the table wasn't filled until I cliccked with the mouse on it, that is another problem, if you face it you can solve it by scrolling down or up by 1 pixel after creating the table